# Is there a group operation $\star$ such that $(\mathbb{R}^2, \star) \cong (\mathbb{C}, \cdot)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I came across this question (slightly rephrased) "Is there a group operation $\star$ such that $(\mathbb{R}^2, \star) \cong (\mathbb{C}, \cdot)$?" in my textbook. A bijection from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ is clear but there's another condition for isomorphism and I'm not sure how everything works with the multiplication. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: First of all $\mathbb{C}$ is literally defined as $\mathbb{R}^2$ together with fancy multiplication. Secondly, $(\mathbb{C},\cdot)$ is not a group. Did you mean to say $(\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}, \cdot)$? Then the answer is yes, because you can transfer multiplicaton from $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ through any bijection (which exists).

Comment: Trite answer: yes, regardless of $\cdot$ is defined on $\mathbb{C}$. Take any bijection $\phi:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{C}$. Then for $x, y\in\mathbb{C}$ define $x\star y:=\phi^{-1}(\phi(x)\cdot\phi(y))$, i.e. define their product to be corresponding product in $\mathbb{C}$, where "corresponding" is defined via $\phi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, $(\mathbb{C},\cdot)$ is not a group. $(\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\},\cdot)$ is.

You have a natural isomorphism between this group and $(\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{(0,0)\},\star)$ with the operation defined as:
$$(a,b)\star(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$$

Comment: Your operation does not define a group. For instance, $(0,0)$ is not invertible.

Comment: @JoshuaTilley, thank you, fixed it. :)